# Вывести значения одного списка по индексам другого

Tags: python, индексация

Найти индекс объекта с ценой меньше 1000, получить адрес с тем же индексом из списка addresses — и сохраните его в addresses_with_low_price. Получил индексы из первого [1, 3] списка , надо вывести адреса по индексам первого списка .

```
prices = [1100, 999, 1000000, 80, 40000]
addresses = ['Берсеневская набережная, 6с1',
             'Болотная набережная, 11с1',
             'Москва, Романов переулок, 4',
             'Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1',
             'Москва, Волгоградский проспект, 32к8']

addresses_with_low_price = []
index_with_low_price = []

# ваш код здесь
for index in range(len(prices)):
    if prices[index] <= 1000:
        index_with_low_price.append(index) # индексы объектов , цена которых ниже 1000
        

print(addresses_with_low_price) # список  объектов , цена которых ниже 1000
#print(index_with_low_price)
```

Comment: Сразу делайте `addresses_with_low_price.append(addresses[index])` вместо `index_with_low_price.append(index)`. Сохранять индексы совсем не обязательно.

Comment: Ну и, в принципе, создать требуемый список можно одной строчкой `addresses_with_low_price = [address for price, address in zip(prices, addresses) if price <= 1000]`.

Comment: Но ведь натурально тут индексы вообще не нужны, нужен только `zip` двух списков и цикл по нему.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте numpy:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.array(addresses)[np.where(np.array(prices)<1000)].tolist()
```

теперь у вас в res:

```
['Болотная набережная, 11с1', 'Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1']
```

Comment: или аналогично, но с pandas: `from pandas import Series as S ;
res = S(addresses)[S(prices)<1000].to_list()`

Answer (score 2):

А в чём проблема сразу после нахождения нужного объекта вносить его в список, без занесения в отдельный список индексов?

```py
prices = [1100, 999, 1000000, 80, 40000]
addresses = ['Берсеневская набережная, 6с1',
             'Болотная набережная, 11с1',
             'Москва, Романов переулок, 4',
             'Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1',
             'Москва, Волгоградский проспект, 32к8']

addresses_with_low_price = []

for index in range(len(prices)):
    if prices[index] <= 1000:
        addresses_with_low_price.append(addresses[index]) # объекты, цена которых ниже 1000

print(addresses_with_low_price)

-------

['Болотная набережная, 11с1', 'Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1']
```

Answer (score 2):

### *На првах фантазии на тему...*

```py
prices = [1100, 999, 1000000, 80, 40000]
addresses = ['Берсеневская набережная, 6с1',
             'Болотная набережная, 11с1',
             'Москва, Романов переулок, 4',
             'Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1',
             'Москва, Волгоградский проспект, 32к8']

print(
    *[
        address for price, address in 
        filter(lambda x: x[0] < 1000, zip(prices, addresses))
    ], 
    sep='\n'
)
#Болотная набережная, 11с1
#Москва, Старая Басманная улица, 20к1

print(
    *[
        address for price, address in 
        zip(prices, addresses) if price < 1000
    ], 
    sep='\n'
)
# Даст идентичный результат
```

> *Будет работать только при условии если длина обоих списков одинокова*

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант списковые включения без zip:

```
index = [i for i, v in enumerate(prices) if v < 1000]

print([v for i, v in enumerate(addresses) if i in index])
```

Или все вместе:

print([v for i, v in enumerate(addresses) if i in (i for i, v in enumerate(prices) if v < 1000)])